# Change python version from 3.6 to 3.11 on Oracle Linux 7

Tags: software-installation, python3, oracle-linux

I am not too experienced with Oracle Linux 7 and Python and I hope you can please help me. For the last few days, I tried to make python 3.11 active.

I downloaded an Oracle 19 appliance. When I do

```
python --version
```

it says `3.6.8`. I like to use 3.11 and I installed it, but it is in `/home/oracle/Downloads/Python-3.11.0`.

So now I am wondering how I can get the system to use the new version.

- I added python to the `PATH`.
- When I do `which python3`, I get `/usr/bin/python3`

What do I need to do to get the new version recognized?

Comment: How did you add python to the PATH? Perhaps `PATH=/home/oracle/Downloads/Python-3.11.0:$PATH`? If the `python3` binary is in a `bin` subdirectory you'll need to add that specifically to the path. Don't do this system-wide as you might break utilities that depend on the earlier version of python.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am actually not sure how to add it locally only. I will see if I can find that solution and if that will resolve the issue.
Actually, looks like my PATH is a big mess, it did not look like that a few hours ago.
Need to revisit this.
(sqlalchemy-workspace) [oracle@localhost ~]$ echo $PATH
/u01/app/oracle/product/version/db_1/bin:/home/oracle/Desktop/Database_Track/coffeeshop:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/git/bin